# Declaring XML Tags in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby to pull information from an excel sheet and with this information produce an xml file. I need to produce this in Ruby:

What I want:

```
<Betrag waehrung="EUR">150000</Betrag>
```

What I have:

```
<Betrag waehrung ="EUR"/>
```

I am currently trying `xml.Betrag "Waehrung": "Eur"`
 the Betrag has a row Identifier of "#{row[13]}" which is where it can be found on the excel sheet I am using. I have tried: `xml.Betrag "Waehrung": ("Eur"), ("#{row[13]}")` with no success, could you please advise?

Comment: Are you using nokogiri for this? If so, take a look at the examples here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder

Comment: Hi, Yes using Nokogiri, I am ok with the language used and how it should be formatted just not when there is a tag within a tag this is confusing me.

Comment: Please include the nokigiri-part in your question, otherwise its hard to guess what the xml-Object refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.Betrag(waehrung: 'EUR') do  |e|
    e << '150000'
  end
end
puts builder.to_xml


=>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Betrag waehrung="EUR">150000</Betrag>
```

Comment: This does not work, xml.Betrag ("waehrung": "EUR") |e| e << "#{row[13]}"

Comment: it says unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input end

Comment: you are not using the correct syntax. Use this
```xml.Betrag(waehrung: 'EUR') { |e| e << '15000' } ```

Comment: E is determined by the value in a cell in a particular row so I cant declare it as a constant because its changing all the time so betrag column in excel could be like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6 and each representation of e should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 like this.

Comment: Can't you replace ```'15000'``` with ```"#{row[13]}"```?
It will be like
```xml.Betrag(waehrung: 'EUR') { |e| e << "#{row[13]}" }```

Comment: I would if I knew how to!

Comment: @George123 Come on! Use your favorite internet search engine or the stackoverflow help! If you can read excel and write XML using ruby you can ***** find that out in under 2 minutes!